# that name does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, scope

In `case 3:` I wrote `mutteer(ba, bb,  bc, bd, be);` which seems to give the error (*The name ba does not exist in current context*).
It gives the same error with `bb` `bc` `bd` and `be`.

What did I do wrong?

I removed most of the unnecessary code:

```
static void menu()
    {
        int loop = 4;
        Console.WriteLine(" 3  Mutteer Voorraad");

        while (loop > 2)
            {
            var ans = Console.ReadLine();
            mp3();
            int choice = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(ans, out choice))
            {
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Mutteer Voorraad.");
                        mutteer(ba, bb,  bc, bd, be);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong selection!!!");
                        Thread.Sleep(1800);
                        Console.Clear();
                        goto top;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must type numeric value only!!!");
                Thread.Sleep(1800);
                Console.Clear();
                goto top;
            }
        }
    }

static void mp3()
    {
        int ba = 500;
        int bb = 500;
        int bc = 500;
        int bd = 500;
        int be = 500;

        mp3players mp1 = new mp3players();
        mp1.id = 1;
        mp1.VR = ba;
     }

static void mutteer(int ba, int bb,  int bc, int bd, int be)
     {
        int i = 1;
        int a;

        startloop:
        while (i == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wat is het Id van de mp3 speler?");
                try
                {
                    a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Dat is geen nummer waarde!");
                    goto startloop;
                }

                if (a == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wat is het nieuwe voorraad");
                    try
                    {
                        i = 2;
                        ba = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Dat is geen nummer waarde!");
                        goto startloop;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error is exactly what the message says. There is no meaning for `ba` at the point you used it.

Comment: I made a quick edit perhaps that changed what you said, If it didn't I would like to ask how I make it so it has a meaning.

Comment: If you are new to C# then please read Scope of variable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the declarations of `ba` and the other variables to the global scope. As the code is currently written, they're accessible only in the scope of the `mp3` method. You should have:

```
static int ba = 500;
static int bb = 500;
static int bc = 500;
static int bd = 500;
static int be = 500;

  static void mp3()
    {
    mp3players mp1 = new mp3players();
    mp1.id = 1;
    mp1.VR = ba;
    }
```